# How to make jQuery dialog popup stay in the center of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How to make jQuery popup stay in the center of the screen even while I'm scrolling up/down or change the size of the browser window?

This div is supposed to hold the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <h3 id="deleteMessage"></h3>
</div>
```

and there is the dialog jQuery code:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Confirm Delete",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        minWidth: 440,
        minHeight: 220,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
```

there is also this code that will show the popup message depending on the id of the datatable element I have selected

```
$("#deleteMessage").html('Are you sure you want to delete "' +"<b>"+ selectedItemName +"</b>"+ '" report?');
```

Comment: It appears that you got an answer to your original question of how to get the dialog to stay centered. Please don't edit your question to add further questions. Rather, just ask a new one. Make sure the new one stands on it own, and of course follows the usual rules for questions on SO.

Comment: no, it didn't asnwer the question, cuz I added (editet) in the question what other problem it causes

Comment: No, it answered your original question, which brought up an **additional** problem, which should be asked in an **additional** question. Please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296489/215552

Comment: Ok. I made an other question with the specific details about the same topic. I am gonna delete this one, so if you can help me get an answer, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969544/how-to-make-jquery-dialog-popup-stay-in-the-center-of-browser-specific-situatio

Comment: Don't delete this question; then the people who helped you lose their rep. Just roll it back to its original state.

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```
#dialog{
  position: fixed;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: can you explain me what transform: translate(-50%, -50%); does? please

Comment: This property allows you to rotate, scale, move, skew

Comment: ohh... this is the css code... sorry, i thought it was jQuery code

Comment: now there is an other problem: Only the content (text inside the div that holds the popup) of the popup moves with the screen, the dialog itself doesn't follow the screen.

Answer (score 1):

if you dont't want to write any css and want to use jquery use code below. Just user your id instead of modal1

```
setTimeout(function () {
          $("#modal1").css({
                "top": ($(window).scrollTop()) + ($(window).height() - $("#modal1").height() - 200) / 2,
                "left":($(window).width() - $("#modal1").width())/2
          });
    }, 250);
```

you just need to put this code in open function of your code like below

```
dialogDiv.dialog({
title: "Confirm Delete",
autoOpen: false,
width: 470,
height: 200,
modal: true,
draggable: false,
resizable: false,
closeOnEscape: false,
create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-100px', 'left': '50%;', 'margin-left': '-235px' }); },
open: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
          $("#modal1").css({
                "top": ($(window).scrollTop()) + ($(window).height() - $("#modal1").height() - 200) / 2,
                "left":($(window).width() - $("#modal1").width())/2
          });
    }, 250);
    },
 buttons: {
        "Delete": function () {                    
            $("#repFilterId").val(selectedItemId);
            $("#deleteForm").submit();

            clearLastValues();
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            clearLastValues();
            dialogDiv.dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you explain me a bit more where to put this code

Comment: put this code where your modal popup is open event you have written. Or better can you also write your html code in question.

Comment: there isn't actually much more code than in the question, but I've made a question with more details, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969544/how-to-make-jquery-dialog-popup-stay-in-the-center-of-browser-specific-situatio

Comment: I still don't understand where to put the code. Can you edit the answer with more details? @nirmal

Comment: @Arianit you can copy your answer from above thing now.

Comment: the message disappears after 1 second when the dialog opens

Comment: @Arianit can you create a fiddle for it ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j8vfxbs0/3/ I made it work with this code. but i have some problems in google chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your jQuery

position: ['center', 'center']

So your jQuery code would look something like:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "Confirm Delete",
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        position: ['center', 'center'],
        closeOnEscape: false,
        minWidth: 440,
        minHeight: 220,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the popup appears on the left top side, under the other divs!

Comment: Do you have CSS on that page?  Such as containers or anything that is doing some alignment?

Answer (score 0):

I am more in favor of simple vanilla JS code when it comes to simple things like this, but you could try with CSS, I guess:

```
#dialog{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: (your width * 1/2);
    margin-top: (your height * 1/2)
}
```

That's like `translate(50%, 50%)` but has better support. I guess the only  disadvantage is that you need to know the width and height.

Comment: but then it is not responsive for different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

.ui-dialog {
    position: fixed !important;

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please update your answer with more information to make it more relevant. This would help everyone coming to this question later.

Comment: i do not know if there are any drawbacks but it helped me, thanks pal!