# How to make jQuery dialog popup stay in the center of browser (specific situation)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How to make jQuery popup stay in the center of the screen even while I'm scrolling up/down or change the size of the browser window? The scenario is like this: to delete a record of the database that are shown in a datatable. So in a Asp.Net MVC project, each datatable element has its own detail, edit and delete actions.

This div is supposed to hold the dialog:

```
<div id="dialog">
  <h3 id="deleteMessage"></h3>
</div>
```

and there is the dialog jQuery code:

```
var dialogDiv = $("#dialog");
var selectedItemId = null;
var selectedItemName = null;

  dialogDiv.dialog({
    title: "Confirm Delete",
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
        },
        buttons: {
            "Delete": function () {                    
                $("#repFilterId").val(selectedItemId);
                $("#deleteForm").submit();

                clearLastValues();
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                clearLastValues();
                dialogDiv.dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

function btnDeleteClick(itemID, itemName) {
        selectedItemId = itemID;
        selectedItemName = itemName;

        $("#deleteMessage").html('Are you sure you want to delete "' +
            "<b>" + selectedItemName + "</b>" + '" report filter?');

        dialogDiv.dialog("open");
```

When I add some css like (from an answer that I got):

```
#dialog{
   position: fixed;
   top:50%;
   left:50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   }
```

I get this problem:
[image]

the text "are you sure you want to delete..." stays in the center of the screen while the popoup dialog stays where it appears in the beginning and goes up/down with the page content (those 2 are separated from each-other!)

Comment: If possible provides JSfilddle or SO - code demo.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j8vfxbs0/1/

Comment: I think external resources links are missing please Include related files.

Comment: everything is in place, jquery-ui.js and .css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give your dialog a `height` and `width` you can use the `create` initiator to pass it some css like this:

```
dialogDiv.dialog({
title: "Confirm Delete",
autoOpen: false,
width: 470,
height: 200,
modal: true,
draggable: false,
resizable: false,
closeOnEscape: false,
create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-100px', 'left': '50%;', 'margin-left': '-235px' }); },
open: function(event, ui) {
    $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
    },
 buttons: {
        "Delete": function () {                    
            $("#repFilterId").val(selectedItemId);
            $("#deleteForm").submit();

            clearLastValues();
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            clearLastValues();
            dialogDiv.dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

See this JSfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/mjt25cap/

Comment: should I copy paste the code you wrote here or that in the jsfiddler?

Comment: copy the `width` and `height` and the `create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-100px', 'left': '50%;', 'margin-left': '-235px' }); },` add those to your code and it should work

Comment: ok, this code you wrote here as answer works. But when I change the browser size, the popup dialog appears somewhere else, when making it smaller I cant find it (it appears outside the content, I just cant see it border), when making it bigger (from small) the popup appears somewhere else (left site of the browser)... is there any way to make it to fix in center when I change browser size?

Comment: should I put the div responsible for the popup inside the content div, maybe, or give it some css style?

Comment: look at my jsfiddle again. I've changed it to accomodate a window resize event. So copy the `$(window).on(...` part and replace the `create: function (event) { $(event.target).parent().css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '50%', 'margin-top': '-100px', 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': '-235px' }).addClass('dialogOnResize'); },` into your code...

Comment: as much as I see, I don't need the margin-top and margin-left

Comment: It almost works, just by resizing it goes a bit to the left, this is a problem only when changing into small size (from big)

Comment: on my jsfiddle it works perfectly, so I am thinking there might be some other css on your page affecting the dialog box. I really can't help you much unless you post your entire exact code onto a jsfiddle.

Comment: in Asp.Net there are some containers calles RenderBody, so they keep the content of specific views inside it, and there is a layout that keeps all the .js and .css references and the layout that is same for each page. This code I am showing in the question is from that specific view only (except hiding the table header and the .css row class in which the table is inside). wait, i play a bit with the margins

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, your dialog width is set to 470px so if you shrink the screen to something smaller to 470 then the dialog will behave like you described. to counter this you must set a smaller width on your dialog (and change the `create` css accordingly, or write more code on the `resize` event to first shrink the dialog to a smaller width and then reposition it in the center.

Comment: i changed the minWidth to 340 earlier... and now I played a bit with the margin-left, made it -180px. it kinda works now( at least for my screen). it's not perfect, but good enough to keep moving. thanks for the answer. p.s. shouldn't I include the transform: translate(-50%, -50%); attribute too?

Comment: I'm not sure where the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` came from, so it's your definite call...

Comment: it was in my question... it is supposed to allows to rotate, scale, move, skew